# How can I center only one tab from MUI in a grid using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an arraw of tabs. They have to share the available space when there's more than one tab. But when there's only one tab, it has to be in the middle of the column. How can I fix this?
I'm using flex but the issue is with one or two tabs.
Here is the code:

```
import type { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

import { Box, Tab, Typography, useMediaQuery, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import Tabs, { tabsClasses } from '@mui/material/Tabs';

const MOCK_TAB_VALUES = [
    { month: 'August 2023', date: '20.08.2023' },
    // { month: 'September 2023', date: '15.09.2023' },
    // { month: 'October 2023', date: '20.10.2023' },
    // { month: 'November 2023', date: '15.11.2023' },
    // { month: 'December 2023', date: '15.11.2023' },
];

export const FormTabComponent = (): ReactElement => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState <number>(0);
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isLargeScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('lg'));

    const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    };
    const isDarkMode = theme.palette.mode === 'dark';
    return (
      <Tabs
        sx={{
                width: 1,
                position: 'relative',
                height: '60px',
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                [`& .${tabsClasses.scrollButtons}`]: {
                    '&.Mui-disabled': { opacity: 0, width: 0 },
                },
                [`& .MuiTabScrollButton-root`]: {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
                '& .MuiTabScrollButton-root:first-child': {
                    zIndex: 1, //to see through the button
                    position: 'absolute',
                    background: isDarkMode
                        ? 'linear-gradient(90deg, #222221, transparent)'
                        : 'linear-gradient(90deg, #FDFDFD, transparent)',
                    '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                        width: '24px',
                        height: '24px',
                    },
                },
                '& .MuiTabScrollButton-root:last-child': {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    right: 0,
                    background: isDarkMode
                        ? 'linear-gradient(270deg, #222221, transparent)'
                        : 'linear-gradient(270deg, #FDFDFD, transparent)',
                    '& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
                        width: '24px',
                        height: '24px',
                    },
                },
                //it modifies both buttons simultaneously
                [`& .${tabsClasses.scrollButtons}`]: {
                    '&.Mui-disabled': { opacity: 0 },
                },
        }}
        value={value}
        variant="scrollable"
        onChange={handleTabChange}
      >
        {MOCK_TAB_VALUES.map((tab, index) => (
          <Tab
            key={index}
            sx={{ flex:1 }}
            label={(
              <Box
                sx={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  variant={isLargeScreen ? 'headings.h4' : 'buttons.small'}
                  color="inherit"
                >
                  {`${tab.month.slice(0, 3)} ${tab.month.slice(-4)}`}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant="captions.default" color="inherit">
                  {tab.date}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            )}
          />
      ))}
      </Tabs>
  );
};
```

Here is a picture. As you can see it is not in the middle of the grid.
[image]

here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-johnson-n5rqpd?file=/FormTabComponent.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please check the below solution? Hope it will work for you.

you have add style in `<Tab sx={{ flex: 1 }} >` to make centred Tab you have add margin in that like..

```
<Tab sx={{ flex: 1, margin: "0px auto" }} >
```

you can also check it in this link
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-bird-sh6w25

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: You're very welcome! I'm glad I could assist you.